# Find a function from graph

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a greater "trouble". I wanna learn more about "graphs". On [this webpage](http://thinktosuccess.tumblr.com/post/4895232488/heart-graphs) I found some nice graphs in heart shape. And they where written as functions. Another graph I found was "the batman (equation) graph".

I would really like to know how to create some functions on my own. Is their any manual? I think it is important - in physics and chemistry we have to look close at graphs and figure out which function we can fit them to. Often we can find some evidence in text - but once we got a random plot in physics, where the instructor just told us which function we should fit it to.

I would like to know such an important thing on my own. Could you maybe write a little - so I can understand how to make my "own" functions by looking at a graph?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

All graphs may not be represented by functions but every function has a graph.
You can look into the book Calculus by Finney.